# How to convert SVG path into .svg file and link dynamic images with coordinates

Tags: html, svg

I'm designing a web page with a really big SVG of a world map, really huge. My issue is that I can import it into the HTML directly using `<path>` but this causes page loading errors on some devices due to it being so huge. I then decided to try and find a way to compress this into some smaller code.

I tried saving the whole  as a file `file.svg` and load it directly into my html using `<img src="{% static 'PNG/file.svg' %}" />` , but it doesn't load the dynamic images i've added to specific coordinates.

So how can I convert my SVG path to a .svg file and keep the dynamic images with their respective coordinates?

My current code that works but is way to large:

```
<svg style="fill: #142236; overflow-x: hidden;" class="Map" viewBox="0 -213 1766.961 874.341">
                    <path>Longdata......</path>
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="100" x="300" y="10" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="600" x="230" y="-70" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="300" x="900" y="-60" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="400" x="1050" y="-120" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="500"  x="1150" y="20" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="1200"  x="1250" y="-140" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="200" x="580" y="-280" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="700" x="900" y="300" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="800" x="820" y="100" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="900" x="490" y="280" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="1000" x="1420" y="330" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                    <image data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="203" data-aos-delay="1100"  x="1300" y="0" width="80" height="290" xlink:href="{% static 'PNG/golem.png' %}" />
                  </svg>
```

Whole SVG code:
https://pastebin.com/rU3GeTvU

Comment: Instead of using a path for the world map, why don't you use a gif? Also: you can get simpler paths for the world map, for example this one: https://d-maps.com/m/world/centreeurope/centreeurope02.svg

Answer (score 0):

If it is the length of path that is the problem, then you can just split the path wherever there is an "M" command.

ie. change:

```
<path id="Map" d="M 895.4368896484375 152.4791412353516 C 893.6979370117188 151.6047668457031 890.8810424804688 153.2721557617188 891.3057250976563 154.4424896240234 C 891.5921020507813 155.2454223632813 892.7576293945313 156.2630462646484 896.3822021484375 157.2088317871094 C 900.0067138671875 158.1550140380859 900.4414672851563 160.6248321533203 901.9644775390625 160.7012634277344 C 903.4885864257813 160.7730712890625 903.6312866210938 159.3158416748047 903.2685546875 157.3520812988281 C 902.90576171875 155.388671875 905.0786743164063 153.1334381103516 905.2980346679688 152.7705841064453 C 905.5126953125 152.4073181152344 904.357421875 151.8244171142578 901.3822631835938 152.4791412353516 C 898.4069213867188 153.1334381103516 897.179931640625 153.35302734375 895.4368896484375 152.4791412353516 Z M 871.577880859375 143.1622314453125 C 870.9236450195313 146.0003814697266 871.9405517578125 149.5692443847656 873.6073608398438 147.892333984375 C 875.2791137695313 146.2249298095703 876.0765991210938 147.0228576660156 877.0173950195313 145.7853088378906 C 877.9577026367188 144.5480499267578 877.1605834960938 139.9660949707031 877.81494140625 137.7823944091797 C 878.4688720703125 135.5990142822266 874.9110107421875 134.576904296875 873.3161010742188 135.9573516845703 C 871.7259521484375 137.3431549072266 870.40771484375 135.7184753417969 869.7676391601563 136.8317565917969 C 868.9657592773438 138.2175750732422 872.2321166992188 140.3245391845703 871.577880859375 143.1622314453125 Z M 1351.581298828125 368.0840759277344 C...
```

to

```
<g id="Map">
  <path d="M 895.4368896484375 152.4791412353516 C 893.6979370117188 151.6047668457031 890.8810424804688 153.2721557617188 891.3057250976563 154.4424896240234 C 891.5921020507813 155.2454223632813 892.7576293945313 156.2630462646484 896.3822021484375 157.2088317871094 C 900.0067138671875 158.1550140380859 900.4414672851563 160.6248321533203 901.9644775390625 160.7012634277344 C 903.4885864257813 160.7730712890625 903.6312866210938 159.3158416748047 903.2685546875 157.3520812988281 C 902.90576171875 155.388671875 905.0786743164063 153.1334381103516 905.2980346679688 152.7705841064453 C 905.5126953125 152.4073181152344 904.357421875 151.8244171142578 901.3822631835938 152.4791412353516 C 898.4069213867188 153.1334381103516 897.179931640625 153.35302734375 895.4368896484375 152.4791412353516 Z"/>
  <path d="M 871.577880859375 143.1622314453125 C 870.9236450195313 146.0003814697266 871.9405517578125 149.5692443847656 873.6073608398438 147.892333984375 C 875.2791137695313 146.2249298095703 876.0765991210938 147.0228576660156 877.0173950195313 145.7853088378906 C 877.9577026367188 144.5480499267578 877.1605834960938 139.9660949707031 877.81494140625 137.7823944091797 C 878.4688720703125 135.5990142822266 874.9110107421875 134.576904296875 873.3161010742188 135.9573516845703 C 871.7259521484375 137.3431549072266 870.40771484375 135.7184753417969 869.7676391601563 136.8317565917969 C 868.9657592773438 138.2175750732422 872.2321166992188 140.3245391845703 871.577880859375 143.1622314453125 Z"/>
  <path d="M 1351.581298828125 368.0840759277344 C...
  ...etc...
</g>
```

You don't have to split at every `M`.  Just make each path small enough to not be too long.

Note also be careful to keep lakes and inland seas in the same path as the country they belong with.

But ultimately, it might be easier for you to just find a version of the world map that doesn't have everything in one path.  There are many free SVG world maps available on the web.